# How do I remove a section from the Visual Studio Code left side bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently re-downloaded Visual Studio Code, but I'm having troubles trying to remove a section in the left side bar. That section is called `WWW` and it's from the `ftp-simple` extension. If you don't know what it is, it's a simple extension that allows you to connect to a remove server and manage the files from your editor.

I've uninstalled the extension but the section is still there.

Is there a way to remove it permanently?

[image: Here the section I'm talking about]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the View menu and select Open View. A panel opens and you can select what is displayed in sidebar. If you don't want anything displayed you can hide the sidebar by going to View/Appearance/Toggle Sidebar.

Comment: It works perfectly, I've also removed the extension so it won't add that folder anymore. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for letting me know and for accepting my answer.